# Time matching (mention time match with current time)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a project to match the mention time in html for ex:-

#### 4:00 pm

with a downlod button my question is if anyone click on downlod button if the mention time is less than current time the is display message file is not uploded else downlode will start so please help me how i write code for this.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried yet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You have to put atleast some effort to solve your own problem, before others are willing to help. Please check out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)